# ASP.NET - Saving recorded videos using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, recordrtc

I've been trying to solve this for days and I can't find out what's going wrong. I'm a beginner on C# and javascript so that might be a big factor. So I record a video from my webcam using RecordRTC.js. Getting the recordedBlob from that, I want to save it somewhere in my Solution.
Here's my code in sending the blob in the code-behind:

```
recordedBuffer.replace('data:video/mp4;base64,', '')
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'BasePage.aspx/UploadVideo',
                data: '{ "video" : "' + recordedBuffer + '" }',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("SUCCESS: " + data.d);
                }, error: function (xhr, err) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
```

And then in C#:

```
[WebMethod()]
    public static string UploadVideo(string video)
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
        string fileNameWitPath = MapPathStatic("~/Gallery/Videos/" + date.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".mp4");
//MapPathStatic is a static version I made of Server.MapPath()

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {

            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(video);
            bw.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            bw.Close();

            return fileNameWitPath;
        }
    }
}
```

The file is being created in the proper file. But when I try to play it, it said it cannot render the file. This is only 1-2 second video. So the video is being corrupted midway? What am doing wrong? Why is it not rendering correctly.
I've also found solutions using PHP to save the file but I really would like to use C# for this.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You send a huge data as Base64String, that is make it even longer - all that process is correct ? Are you send the correct data ? Do you get any error ? Do you have the correct decoding ? Do you have debug your code step by step to see what you actually saves there ?

Comment: Oh, you placed me in the right track! Apparently, the string I'm send is not being detected as Base64 because of some additional characters (the 'data=video/mp4;base64,'). I just needed to trim that part and it works!!! Thank you so much!